# SQL error when trying to use GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY in CockroachDb

Tags: sql, cockroachdb

I'm trying to create a simple table auto auto-generated identity key, but Cockroachdb is throwing a syntax error for the keyword `GENERATED`. Is there something I'm missing?

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "users"
(
    "id" bigint GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    "age" bigint NOT NULL, 
    "name" varchar NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    "email" varchar NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CockroachDB appears to use [`SERIAL`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/serial.html) for this purpose:

```
"id" serial8 primary key,
```

Note that because Cockroach is a distributed databases, this introduces contention and `SERIAL` is not recommended for assigning unique ids to rows.

Comment: I guess the preferred way when using a distributed database would be to use `uuid`s instead.

Comment: @SohamDasgupta . . . Yes.  That eliminates contention in the parallel environment.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use `unique_rowid` instead. It is time-ordered. I have used it successfully for a streaming data ingest application.

If your application performs a lot of concurrent inserts, you could potentially use `uuid_v4`. It is unordered, but it doesn't slow down inserts on concurrent connections.